# unique_ptr and failed memory allocation

Tags: c++

I want to create a unique pointer using `unique_ptr<A>(new A)` (not `make_unique()`).

The `unique_ptr` constructor is `noexcept`, however `new` may throw `bad_alloc`.

So my question is, whether I should expect an exception calling `unique_ptr<A>(new A)` in case `new` fails or not?

I tried to check that and I'm getting 'abort' in the code below, whereas I expected to see `"null"` on the screen. So it seems, that in case `new` fails, `unique_ptr` will throw an exception.

Is that correct?

```cpp
class A
{
  public:
  int vec[1000000000];
};

int main()
{
  A* a[100000];
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
  {
    a[i] = unique_ptr<A>(new A).release();
    if (!a[i])
    {
      cout << "null" << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note: The only goal of this code is to cram the memory so that `new` fails.

Comment: [Obligatory link to `std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is, whether I should expect an exception calling `unique_ptr<A>(new A)` in case `new` fails or not?

Yes. If `new` fails, it will throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception, and the `std::unique_ptr` object will not even be constructed at all.

> I tried to check that and I'm getting 'abort' in the code below, whereas I expected to see `"null"` on the screen. So it seems, that in case `new` fails, `unique_ptr` will throw an exception. Is that correct?

No. `new` is the one throwing the exception, not the `std::unique_ptr` constructor (which it can't anyway due to being `noexcept`, as you noted).  Since `new` is being called *outside* of the constructor, the constructor being marked as `noexcept` is irrelevant.

If you want to avoid the `std::bad_alloc` exception being thrown, use the [`std::nothrow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow) version of `new`, eg:

```cpp
#include <new>

a[i] = unique_ptr<A>(new(nothrow) A).release();
```

Alternatively, since your use of `unique_ptr().release()` defeats the whole purpose of `std::unique_ptr`, just omit it entirely:

```cpp
a[i] = new(nothrow) A;
```

Don't forget to `delete` whatever is successfully `new`'ed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have

```
void foo(int) noexcept {}
int bar() { throw 42; }

int main(){
    foo(bar());
}
```

Then `foo` is not called because already `bar()` throws.

> So it seems, that in case new fails, unique_ptr will throw an exception.

No, the `unique_ptr` constructor is not being called when `new` throws.